# Simple Python turn based battle game

Tags: python, beginner, python-3.x, game

As I mentioned in my bio, I do not code for a living and too old to switch careers but I do enjoy it as a hobby and I am trying to get better. Also trying to get my teenage son more interested. Anyhow, the code below does want I want it to but I am looking for tips to improve it. Any advice would be much appreciated before I add more to it with High Score tables and more functionality.

```
import random
weapons = ["Sword", "Spell", "Fire"]
shields = ["Armour", "Magic", "Water"]

class Player:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.health = 100
        self.weapon = 0
        self.shield = 0

    def damage(self):
        points = random.randint(10, 35)
        self.health -= points

    def selectWeapon(self):
        choice = int(input("Choose your weapon 1-Sword, 2-Spell or 3-Fire:  "))
        self.weapon = choice - 1

    def selectShield(self):
        choice = int(input("Choose your shield 1-Armour, 2-Magic or 3-Water:  "))
        self.shield = choice - 1


# Child class of player with override methods for weapon
# and shield selection
class AiPlayer(Player):
    def __init__(self,name):
        super().__init__(name)

    def selectWeapon(self):
        choice = random.randint(1, 3)
        self.weapon = choice - 1

    def selectShield(self):
        choice = random.randint(1, 3)
        self.shield = choice - 1

class Game:
    def __init__(self):
        self.gameOver = False
        self.round = 0

    def newRound(self):
        self.round += 1
        print("\n***   Round: %d   ***\n" %(self.round))  

    # Check if either or both Players is below zero health
    def checkWin(self, player, opponent):
        if player.health < 1 and opponent.health > 0:
            self.gameOver = True
            print("You Lose")
        elif opponent.health < 1 and player.health > 0:
            self.gameOver = True
            print("You Win")
        elif player.health < 1 and ai.health < 1:
            self.gameOver = True
            print("*** Draw ***")


    def displayResult(self, player, opponent):
            print("%s used a %s, %s used a %s Shield\n" %(player.name, weapons[player.weapon], opponent.name, shields[opponent.shield]))
            print("%s caused damage to %s\n" %(player.name, opponent.name))

    def takeTurn(self, player, opponent):

        # Decision Array
        #
        #           Armour|  Magic |  Water
        #           ______|________|_______
        # Sword:    False |  True  |  True
        # Spell:    True  |  False |  True   
        # Fire :    True  |  True  |  False

        decisionArray = [[False, True, True], [True, False, True], [True, True, False]]
        if decisionArray[player.weapon][opponent.shield]:
            opponent.damage()
            currentGame.displayResult(player, opponent)
        else:
            print("\n%s used a %s, %s used a %s Shield" %(player.name, weapons[player.weapon], opponent.name, shields[opponent.shield]))
            print("%s blocked %s's attack - No Damage" %(opponent.name, player.name))


# Setup Game Objects
currentGame = Game()
human = Player("Mark")
ai = AiPlayer("Computer")

players = [human, ai]

# Main Game Loop
while not currentGame.gameOver:
    for player in players:
        player.selectWeapon()
        player.selectShield()
    currentGame.newRound()
    currentGame.takeTurn(human, ai)
    currentGame.takeTurn(ai, human)
    print("%s's health = %d" %(human.name, human.health))
    print("%s's health = %d" %(ai.name, ai.health))
    currentGame.checkWin(human, ai)
```

Answer (score 22):

## f-strings

Beginning with Python 3.6, there is a friendlier way of formatting strings. Instead of using `"format string" % (tuple_of_args)` where the argument and the format codes are separated by significant distance, the arguments are embedded in the string itself, surrounded by `{}`'s.  The string itself is prefixed with an `f`.

For example, instead of:

```
    print("\n***   Round: %d   ***\n" %(self.round))
```

you can write:

```
    print(f"\n***   Round: {self.round}   ***\n")
```

## Enumerations

This code doesn't convey a lot of meaning by itself.  It needs to be described by your 7 comment lines.

```
    decisionArray = [[False, True, True], [True, False, True], [True, True, False]]
```

Some of the problem stems from indices having semantic meaning.  For example, 1 is Magic.  But 1 is also Spell.  Confusing.

Let's make what is happening a lot clearer.  Let's define enumerations for our weapons and shields:

```
from enum import Enum

Weapon = Enum("Weapon", "Sword, Spell, Fire")
Shield = Enum("Shield", "Armour, Magic, Water")
```

Now we have `Weapon.Sword`, `Weapon.Spell`, and `Weapon.Fire`, which conveniently have values 1, 2 and 3 respectively.  We also have `Shield.Armour`, `Shield.Magic` and `Shield.Water`, also with values 1, 2, and 3.

When we have our player select their `choice` of weapon, we use to store it as the number 0, 1 or 2:

```
    self.weapon = choice - 1
```

but now we can store an actual enumeration object, like `Weapon.Fire` directly.  Conveniently, passing the value 1, 2, or 3 to `Weapon(...)` will return the corresponding enumeration object:

```
    self.weapon = Weapon(choice)
```

Similarly, we can store our shield `choice` as a `Shield` enumeration object:

```
    self.shield = Shield(choice)
```

The AI is similar, but instead of `randint`, we can use `choice` and select a random `Weapon` and random `Shield`:

```
    self.weapon = random.choice(list(Weapon))
    self.shield = random.choice(list(Shield))
```

But how about that `decisionArray`?  First of all, that is a lousy name.  What does "decision array" mean?  A `Shield` will block one (or perhaps more) `Weapon` attacks.  Let's add a `.blocks` attribute to our `Shield` objects:

```
Shield.Armour.blocks = { Weapon.Sword }
Shield.Magic.blocks = { Weapon.Spell }
Shield.Water.blocks = { Weapon.Fire }
```

(I'm using a `set()`, so more that one `Weapon` can be added.  For example, `Shield.Magic` could block both `{ Weapon.Spell, Weapon.Fire }` ... after all, it's **MAGIC**!  Feel free to experiment.)

What would the `takeTurn` method now look like?

```
def takeTurn(self, player, opponent):

    if player.weapon not in opponent.shield.blocks:
        # apply damage
    else:
        # damage was blocked
```

That's pretty straight forward; no table required.  If the weapon is not in the set of things the shield blocks, we apply damage.

## PEP-8

[PEP 8](https://lmgtfy.com/?q=pep+8&s=d) is a Style Guide for Python.  It describes things all Python programs should conform to, such as:

- variables and function names should be `snake_case` not `mixedCase`.

## Updated Code

```
import random
from enum import Enum

Weapon = Enum("Weapon", "Sword, Spell, Fire")
Shield = Enum("Shield", "Armour, Magic, Water")

Shield.Armour.blocks = { Weapon.Sword }
Shield.Magic.blocks = { Weapon.Spell }
Shield.Water.blocks = { Weapon.Fire }

class Player:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.health = 100
        self.weapon = None
        self.shield = None

    def damage(self):
        points = random.randint(10, 35)
        self.health -= points

    def select_weapon(self):
        weapons = [f"{weapon.value}-{weapon.name}" for weapon in Weapon]
        weapons = ", ".join(weapons[:-1]) + " or " + weapons[-1]
        choice = int(input(f"Choose your weapon {weapons}:  "))
        self.weapon = Weapon(choice)

    def select_shield(self):
        shields = [f"{shield.value}-{shield.name}" for shield in Shield]
        shields = ", ".join(shields[:-1]) + " or " + shields[-1]
        choice = int(input(f"Choose your shield {shields}:  "))
        self.shield = Shield(choice)

class AiPlayer(Player):

    def select_weapon(self):
        self.weapon = random.choice(list(Weapon))

    def select_shield(self):
        self.shield = random.choice(list(Shield))

class Game:
    def __init__(self):
        self.game_over = False
        self.round = 0

    def new_round(self):
        self.round += 1
        print(f"\n***   Round: {self.round}   ***\n")  

    # Check if either or both Players is below zero health
    def check_win(self, player, opponent):
        if player.health < 1 and opponent.health > 0:
            self.game_over = True
            print("You Lose")
        elif opponent.health < 1 and player.health > 0:
            self.game_over = True
            print("You Win")
        elif player.health < 1 and ai.health < 1:
            self.game_over = True
            print("*** Draw ***")


    def display_result(self, player, opponent):
            print(f"{player.name} used a {player.weapon.name}, {opponent.name} used a {opponent.shield.name} Shield\n")
            print(f"{player.name} caused damage to {opponent.name}\n")

    def take_turn(self, player, opponent):

        if player.weapon not in opponent.shield.blocks:
            opponent.damage()
            current_game.display_result(player, opponent)
        else:
            print(f"{player.name} used a {player.weapon.name}, {opponent.name} used a {opponent.shield.name} Shield\n")
            print(f"{opponent.name} blocked {player.name}'s attack - No Damage")

# Setup Game Objects
current_game = Game()
human = Player("Mark")
ai = AiPlayer("Computer")

players = [human, ai]

# Main Game Loop
while not current_game.game_over:
    for player in players:
        player.select_weapon()
        player.select_shield()
    current_game.new_round()
    current_game.take_turn(human, ai)
    current_game.take_turn(ai, human)
    print(f"{human.name}'s health = {human.health}")
    print(f"{ai.name}'s health = {ai.health}")
    current_game.check_win(human, ai)
```

Notice in this code, if you added additional weapons and/or shields, nothing need be changed other than the `Enum(...)` declarations and the `.blocks = {}` lines.  The code itself creates the "1-Armour, 2-Magic or 3-Water" type choice strings, and will properly work with more than 3 choices.

Comment: This is awesome thanks very much for all the feedback. It's funny..... The snake case mixed case thing I did read PEP-8, started changing everything to snake case then changed it back. I will stick with the PEP-8 recommendations for future though.

Answer (score 3):

To add to @AJNeufeld's answer, `select_weapon` and `select_shield` should probably validate their input.  Those two functions could be refactored to remove duplicate code.

```
def select_enum(enum_class):
    items = [f"{item.value}-{item.name}" for item in enum_class]
    items = ", ".join(items[:-1]) + " or " + items[-1]

    valid_values = set(item.value for item in enum_class)

    while True:
        choice = int(input(f"Choose your {enum_class.__name__.lower()}: {items}"))
        if choice in valid_values:
            break

        print(f"'{choice}' is not a valid selection. Please try again.")

    return enum_class(choice)


def select_weapon(self):
    self.weapon = self.select_enum(Weapon)


def select_shield(self):
    self.shield = self.select_enum(Shield)
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, much appreciated. I will add it in once I get it straight in my head what each line is doing.

Comment: Okay I get it I was confused by the enum_class.__name__.lower(). I think it is returning the name of module so either Weapon or Shield so that the code works for both selections. Thank you. Learning some cool new code.

Comment: @CelestialMark, you got it.  Every class has a `__name__` attribute, that is the name of the class.  There are several handy "dunder" attributes.

Comment: Nice addition.  If you are validating input, however, you should go further.  Add a `try: ... except ValueError:` to catch non-integer input, like `"quit"`.